# Can Execute Null

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, data-binding

I have run into an issue with WPF and Commands that are bound to a Button on my view, I have been following a tutorial on commands and can't seem to understand why it's getting stuck. The parameter passed to CanExecute is null when it's called

I have a form  with textboxes bound to my properties when I push Add I want to add the stock the the list

My View

```
 <TextBox  Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"   Margin="2"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="178" Text="{Binding Ticker,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                    <DatePicker  Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Name="txtDate"  Margin="2"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="178" Text="{Binding Date,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                    <TextBox  Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3" Name="txtPriceEntry"  Margin="2"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="178" Text="{Binding PreviousClose,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,Mode=TwoWay}" />
                    <TextBox  Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="4" Name="txtOpeningPriceEntry"  Margin="2"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="178"   Text="{Binding OpeningPrice,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,Mode=TwoWay}" />
                    <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="5" Name="txtHighEntry"  Margin="2"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="178"   Text="{Binding High,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,Mode=TwoWay}" />
                    <TextBox  Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="6" Name="txtLowEntry"  Margin="2"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="178"   Text="{Binding Low,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,Mode=TwoWay}" />
                    <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="7" Name="txtClosingPriceEntry"  Margin="2"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="178"  Text="{Binding ClosingPrice,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,Mode=TwoWay}" />
                    <Button Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="8" Name="btnAdd"  Width="100" Height="25" Content="Add" Command="{Binding Command}" />
```

My ViewModel

```
 public ICommand Command
    {

        get
        {
            return _command ?? (_command = new RelayCommand(
       x =>
       {
           AddStock();
       }));
        }

    }

    #endregion 


    #region Actions

    private void AddStock()
    {
        using (var stocks = new AppDbContext())
        {
            stocks.LowFloatStocks.Add(stock);
        }
    }
```

RelayCommand.cs

```
public class RelayCommand<T> : ICommand
{
    private readonly Predicate<T> _canExecute;
    private readonly Action<T> _execute;

    public RelayCommand(Action<T> execute)
       : this(execute, null)
    {
        _execute = execute;
    }

    public RelayCommand(Action<T> execute, Predicate<T> canExecute)
    {
        if (execute == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("execute");
        }
        _execute = execute;
        _canExecute = canExecute;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return _canExecute == null || _canExecute((T)parameter);
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _execute((T)parameter);
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    }
}

public class RelayCommand : ICommand
{
    private readonly Predicate<object> _canExecute;
    private readonly Action<object> _execute;

    public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute)
       : this(execute, null)
    {
        _execute = execute;
    }

    public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Predicate<object> canExecute)
    {
        if (execute == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("execute");
        }
        _execute = execute;
        _canExecute = canExecute;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return _canExecute == null || _canExecute(parameter);
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _execute(parameter);
    }

   
    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add
        {
            CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value;
            CanExecuteChangedInternal += value;
        }
        remove
        {
            CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value;
            CanExecuteChangedInternal -= value;
        }
    }

    private event EventHandler CanExecuteChangedInternal;

    public void RaiseCanExecuteChanged()
    {
        CanExecuteChangedInternal.Raise(this);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't passing `CanExecute` to the Command. Thus it's `null`. And I suggest to rename `Command` to `AddCommand` to avoid naming conflicts.

```csharp
private ICommand _addCommand;

public ICommand AddCommand
{
    get
    {
        return _addCommand ?? (_addCommand = new RelayCommand(
        x =>
        {
            AddStock();
        },
        x => true // Here's optional CanExecute, try return 'false' here
        ));
    }
}
```

Comment: I changed a few things in my RelayCommand class and set the canExecute parameter to null, it still doesn't work, I know I'm missing something stupid here

Comment: ' public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Func<object,bool> canExecute = null)
        {
            this._execute = execute;
            this._canExecute = canExecute;
        }'

Comment: @F.OLeary i don't understand, what really do you want to achieve. Please refer to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2009/february/patterns-wpf-apps-with-the-model-view-viewmodel-design-pattern#relaying-command-logic).

Comment: When I run the program and step into it, it fires the Command and when it hits my CanExecute method in my RelayCommand class it just keeps going through the method?

Comment: @F.OLeary did you try the code from the answer? Did you try return `false` there? It must make the button disabled.

Comment: Yes I tried it and it still does the same thing, and yes I tried the button was disabled when I changed it to false

Comment: @F.OLeary thus, it works as expected. You can use a boolean condition instead of `true` or `false`. This is the CanExecute purpose: prevent the Command execution, when the condition returns `false`.

Comment: But I'm trying to understand why it's not executing,sorry if I'm getting confused

Comment: @F.OLeary `Predicate` is function (method) or condition that returns `bool`.

Comment: Ok I changed my AddCommand to this `public ICommand AddCommand => _addCommand ?? (_addCommand = new RelayCommand(param => this.AddStock(),param=>true));` yet when the canExecute is being called the parameter is null, I don't understand where I'm going wrong

Comment: `param`? It's `CommandParameter="something"` in xaml. Add `CommandParameter` to the Button markup and check then.

Comment: I added just a random parameter to the xaml,it gets passed now but still the same issue

Comment: Add there random string, maybe you wrongly used Binding. Show the markup. Btw, your question is not related to CanExecute but to CommandParameter.

Comment: Ok I added a random string and it's not working also when I asked the question I didn't know it was related to CommandParameter and I don't need to pass anything when I want to fire the method I just want to add the form input to my list, I press the button and it gets hung up on CanExecute

Comment: ` <Button Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="8" Name="btnAdd"  Width="100" Height="25" Content="Add" Command="{Binding AddCommand}" CommandParameter="abcd" />`

Comment: @F.OLeary i still can't catch the idea. And I don't understand the problem. Does the command executes? Why are you focused on CanExecute? It only intended to prevent the command execution. What's exactly `null`? What list do you mean? I don't see any Items Controls in your UI. I don't see any Lists in your ViewModel. Can you take a debugger screenshot where the `null` exactly is? Does the app hangs when you pressing the button?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218880/discussion-between-f-oleary-and-aepot).